# CloudKit: "There is no operation associated with this request"

Tags: ios, cloudkit

When attempting to save a CloudKit CKRecord, I get a CKError returned which gives the following description:

```
 <CKError 0x7fd3d24e1810: "Internal Error" (1/2005); "there is no operation
 associated with this request">
```

Any ideas what might cause this? Google does not return any results at all to this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is mentioned in the CloudKit constants reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CKErrorCode). Clearly this is some sort of internal issue in CK. Is the issue recurring? Are you doing anything special in this operation?

Comment: yes, the issue is recurring. I am simply storing a CKRecord. I think I have figured it out - it seems I am storing data in a way I shouldn't. I'll update once I figure it out.

Comment: The issue was that I had set a row to be of type "String List" but I was attempting to store a List of String Lists instead.